# Ao fazer uma requisição ajax, há problemas se usuário recarregar a página logo em seguida?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Ola, eu estou desenvolvendo um sistema em PHP onde ele trabalha com listas de IPTV armazenadas em serviços como o pastebin. O usuário submete uma url dessas, por exemplo (https://gitlab.com/bieldry02/FilmeseSeries.m3u8/raw/master/FilmeseSeries.m3u8), em um formulário e meu script vai analisar linha por linha do conteúdo da lista. O problema é que o servidor demora muito de responder quando a lista é muito grande. Então a minha ideia é fazer a requisição usando ajax. Só que como o servidor pode demorar a responder, o usuário pode continuar navegando no site, a minha grande dúvida é que se quando o servidor enviar a resposta da requisição haverá algum problema.

Adicionando mais informações:

É um site que tem um painel de usuário, eu quero da a liberdade de ele poder submeter uma lista dessas e enquanto o servidor não envia a resposta, ele continuar navegando normalmente no site.

Comment: Depende de como a navegação da página for feita. Podes explicar mais sobre a página que tens? ela é toda carregada de uma vez ou é dinâmica?

Comment: A página é carregada de uma vez.

Answer (score 2):

Olá @Marcos Silva,

Utiliza o beforeSend() do ajax, quando a lista estiver carregando, mantém o usuário informado de que isso está ocorrendo através de um buffer/preloader, e seria relevante deixar o usuário focado nessa requisição feita por ele mesmo não o deixando clicar em outros botões durante esse processo,
então no success function(), vc obtém o resultado assim que a lista for definitivamente carregada, e o libera para continuar a navegação deixando assim os demais botões disponíveis.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "pasta/",
    beforeSend: function(){

      //buffer preloader
      //bloqueia demais botoes

    },
   success: function( data ){
     setTimeout(function(){

       //carrega a lista completa(com paginação se possivel ou necessario)
       //desbloqueia demais botoes permitindo que o usuario continue sua navegação

     }, 2000);
   }
});

return false;
```

Comment: Mas quero da a liberdade de o usuário poder submeter uma lista dessas e enquanto o servidor não envia a resposta, ele continuar navegando normalmente no site.

Comment: Se o usuário recarregar a página inteira, via http, a lista vai iniciar o carregamento novamente do zero. Então vc precisa organizar essa estrutura de um modo dinâmico. *Vamos imaginar que vc tem um menu com varios links/botões, então cada link deverá ser carregado com ajax, e cada conteudo deverá ser carregado em divs diferentes, dessa forma vc consegue o resultado desejado. $(".lista").load("pasta/lista.php"); $(".conteudo2").load("pasta/conteudo2.php");